# Testcase not failing even if it has actually failed

Tags: java, testng, selenium-grid

I use TestNG and its dataProvider mechanism to run testcases. I run the TCs parallely. I have a single Test method and that method calls the actual testcase logic defined in some other class using reflection.

The testcase logic written in the other class does not have any @Test annotation over its methods.

Now whenever any testcase case throws any exception I catch Exception and then

```
Assert.fail();
```

But in the testNG report it says failed=0 even after some TCs fail.

Why the TC is not failing ??

please help.

Comment: You will have to post at least one code example so that we may review the code to help you find the problem; it's impossible to help you diagnose the problem with just a description. Can you try posting one or two of your testcases and enough of the test method to give context?

Comment: Can you check and ensure that Assert is from testNG itself and not from jUnit?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in my code. I was calling all the methods defined specifically for testcases using reflection. And the actual logic of test case was there in the method being called via reflection. And I was trying to use `Assert.fail()` from there. So the testcase was not getting failed, as the method is not a test as per TestNG, as the method did not have any `@Test` annotation.

I threw a custom exception from all those test methods of mine. And then caught them in the actual test which calls these methods using reflection and there I user the `Assert.fail()` and now the Test Cases are failing properly.