# Test is not failing even though assertion has failed

Tags: testing, testng, assertion

I have the same issue to one stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152560/testcase-not-failing-even-if-it-has-actually-failed), but I would cover it with a code sample that someone can answer it.

The thing is that I have 2 classes. One of them contains `@Test` method which calls `validation` where all asserts are put. The problem arises when that `validation` method is called via reflection, like this:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void test() {

      BaseValidation baseValidation = new BaseValidation();
      baseValidation.validateAll();

    }

}

public class BaseValidation {
    public void validateAll() {
        for (Method method : this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            method.invoke(new ValidationClass(), null);
        }
    }
}

public class ValidationClass extends BaseValidation {
    public void validate() {
        Assert.fail("some message");
    }
}
```

In this case, the overall test will **pass** even though **assertion failed** in validation method. How to fix it? In case I am not using reflection:

```
@Test
public void test() {
  ValidationClass validationClass = new ValidationClass();
  validationClass.validate();    // NOT USING REFLECTION
}
```

it will work, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Are you catching the exceptions thrown by invoke method?  And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Of course, I just omitted it for the sake of cleaner code. I have framework that works on this way, there is no space for restructuring it, just need to make it works properly.

Comment: So if you are catching it, then you should be getting the InvocationTargetException which would be being raised by the AssertionError in the test method.  Since you are catching it, your test is passed.

Comment: Oh right. Even though stackTrace was printed, TestNG didn't count it as exception. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will mark it as an answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are catching exception in the invoke call, then you should be getting the InvocationTargetException which would be being raised by the AssertionError in the test method. Since you are catching it, your test is passed.  Either throw it or get the route cause to mark the test as failed.